# Install ruby gem feedjira on codingground online coding platform

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I cannot install feddjira on Codingground online coding plataform (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php) via

```
gem install feedjira
```

It says

```
sh-4.2# gem install feedjira                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Fetching: sax-machine-1.3.2.gem (100%)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Successfully installed sax-machine-1.3.2                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Fetching: curb-0.8.8.gem (100%)                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...                                                                                                                                                                                                
Killed
```

Feedjira is not installed

```
bash-4.2# gem list                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

*** LOCAL GEMS ***                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

bigdecimal (1.2.0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
feed (0.0.4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
hoe (3.13.1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
io-console (0.4.2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
json (1.7.7)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
psych (2.0.0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
rake (10.4.2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
rdoc (4.0.1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
sax-machine (1.3.2)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
thrift (0.9.2.0)
```

Is there a way to use this feedjira on this platform or are there better alternatives? Alternatives to use feejira here? Alternatives for coding ruby online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It showed that a dependency to libcurl was missing, wich is used by curb, which is a dependency of feedjira.

Finally I switched to Cloud9 https://c9.io/ for simple online ruby programming, because it gives you more freedom. Unfortunately you have to sign up for this.

Answer (score -1):

You problem can be related to memory size available for environment. Seems like for building this gem required more memory than available.

So, I recommend to develop your ruby script locally or purchase a VPS, like Digital Ocean, for development.

Comment: Of course I could do that, but it should be simple online coding similar to codingground.

Comment: Suggesting a VPS here is out of context.